# ID3 tags Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, id3

I am trying to get ID3 tags from MP3 file in Objective-C. I found how to do that with MPMusicPlayer but I am making an application which can play music from URL and MPMusicPlayer is not useful for me, I should use AVPlayer.. Maybe some one can help me with getting ID3 tags from AVPlayer? I need to get Artwork picture.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this](https://github.com/H2CO3/MFMusicLibrary/blob/master/src/MFID3Tag.m).

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *path = @"path/file.mp3";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

NSArray *metadata = [asset commonMetadata];
for ( AVMetadataItem* item in metadata ) {
  NSString *key = [item commonKey];
  NSString *value = [item stringValue];
  NSLog(@"key = %@, value = %@", key, value);
}
```

Comment: how to get audio creation date objective c